# The case of the disappearing locators

Tags: graphics, manipulate

I have a complicated Manipulate that uses multiple locators, and need to document the output by saving the graphics to a file. The problem is that when I try to save the graphics, the locators disappear. Here is a simple case where the same problem occurs:

```
Manipulate[pts = PadRight[pts, n, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {15, 2}]];
 disp = Graphics[Polygon[pts], PlotRange -> 1], {n, 5, 15, 1}, {{pts, {{0, 0}}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

If this looks familiar, it's because this is an example from the documentation for Manipulate, and I have only changed it by adding the `disp =`. In order to save the graphics to a file we can Export, but the problem is already present, since `disp` is

[image]

Notice that the locators have disappeared. So my question is this: is there a way to capture/rasterize/save the complete manipulate image (including the locators)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make the `Locator`s a part of the `Graphics` object instead of the `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[pts = PadRight[pts, n, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {15, 2}]];
 disp = Graphics[{Polygon[pts], PlotRange -> 1, Locator /@ pts}], 
 {n, 5, 15, 1}, {{pts, {{0, 0}}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}]
```

Now you'll get a `disp` that looks like

[image: disp]

Comment: very clever -- I hadn't realized that Locators are just another graphics object.